# HSQLDB: Memory table and data loss

Tags: java, database, hsqldb

Situation: `memory` table is created and database is used as `file:`.  As I understand this case all data must be contained in `.script` file. My question is what happens if hsqldb after some inserts is closed not in a proper way? For example someone pushes power button on server box.

The core of this question is when does hsqldb save data to file when memory tables are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a `.log` file that records all the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements. When the database is restarted, the `.log` file is read and the data is restored to the point of power loss.